# cubism.js and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, d3.js, cubism.js

Last week I finished a website which makes use of d3.js and cubism.js. During development I stumbled across some problems but was always able to fix them. At the project's final meeting my colleague had the idea to open the website in Microsoft's Internet Explorer. It totally failed. Some functions were not executed and absolutely nothing seemed to work. IE threw a whole bunch of "Script87: invalid argument" errors which have their origin in d3's and cubism's code. I am aware of IE's shortcomings and problems it can cause.

Is there a way to make d3.js and cubism.js work with IE? Is there a chance these libraries will become compatible with IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 doesn't support IE 8 or earlier because of the lack of SVG support.  See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/42